# Map over a function with a CSV save inside

Tags: r

I have a function

```
    function_to_load <- function(year){
    myfiles = list.files(paste0("data/",year))
    myfiles = paste(working_directory, "data", year, myfiles, sep = "/")

    parsed_files <- map(myfiles, possibly(parse_filing, otherwise = NA))
    names(parsed_files) = myfiles
    documents <- plyr::compact(parsed_files)
    documents <- plyr::ldply(documents, data.frame)
    management_section <- documents %>%
      filter(tolower(part.name) == tolower("PART II")) %>%
      filter(str_detect(tolower(item.name), item_to_filter)) %>%
      group_by(.id) %>%
      summarise(text = paste(text, collapse=' ')) %>%
      mutate(IDlink = gsub(".*/","", .id)) %>%
      inner_join(., company_information, by = c("IDlink" = "CIKAccNumFileDate_web_extension"))


write.csv(management_section, file = paste(working_directory,"/10-k_parts/management_discussion/",year_to_process,"/mgntdiscus_",year_to_process,".csv", sep = ""))


return(management_section)
}
```

Which basically processes some html files and cleans the data then saves it using `write.csv`.
I then apply the following which calls the function and processes the data for that year.

```
parsed_files <- function_to_load(2005)
```

This works and the file gets saved into the correct folder. However I am trying to do this for all years `2000 - 2019` for example. The following is returning an error:

```
 year_to_process <- c(2000, 2001)

 parsed_files <- Map(function_to_load, year_to_process)
```

Error:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :

 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  invalid 'description' argument
```

I have tried with `lapply` and `walk` also without much luck.

EDIT: Using the following gives a list of 2 with NAs, I was hoping it would have at least got to save the files but it didn`t.

```
parsed_files <- map(year_to_process, possibly(function_to_load, otherwise = NA))
```

Comment: Note that the first two lines as well as the last line of your function can be simplified by using `file.path` instead of `paste`.

Comment: Thanks! and I just solved the issue... the problem was, I was calling `function(year)` and then using the `write.csv()` with `paste0()` - where I had `year_to_process`, changing this part to `year` solved the issue. i.e. `paste(working_directory,"/10-k_parts/management_discussion/",year,"/mgntdiscus_",year,".csv", sep = "")`